# {parents} sort and orderby

Tags: relationships, parent

I have done some searching and am unable to find an answer.  I am trying to sort my entries using the {parents} tag and it does not seem to be working, can anyone confirm this as a bug or know of an alternative way I can accomplish it? I am using EE 2.6.1.

Here are the tag I have attempted with no results, just what seems to be random orders.

```
{parents field="sermon_series" orderby="parents:entry_id" sort="asc"}

{parents field="sermon_series" orderby="parents:date" sort="asc"}

{parents field="sermon_series" orderby="entry_id" sort="asc"}

{parents field="sermon_series" orderby="date" sort="asc"}

{parents field="sermon_series" orderby="" sort="asc"}
```

I appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

2.6.1 has a handful of bugs related to sorting/ordering relationships. Upgrading to 2.7.3 should sort those for you.

Comment: Is there anything i can do without updating up to 2.7.3.  My install is a rather large and complex and previous 2.7.x updates have gone horribly wrong, thanks for the response.

Comment: You could poke around the relationship files in core and see what you could find in terms of making changes yourself, but I'd suggest you just take the time and do the upgrade.